# Jinja's loop variable is not available in include-d templates

Tags: python, jinja2, template-inheritance

I have code similar to the following in one of my jinja template

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% include ["posts/" + post.type + ".html", "posts/default.html"] %}
{% endfor %}
```

which is supposed to render each `post` inside the `posts` collection, depending on the `.type` of the post. I have a different template setup for each `post.type`. And for those I don't have a template, it reverts to the `default` post template.

Now, I want the index of the post being displayed from bottom, inside the post templates, which is provided by `loop.revindex`. But for some reason, if I use `loop.revindex` inside the post template, I get a error saying `UndefinedError: 'loop' is undefined`.

So, is `loop` not available in the `include`d templates? Is this by design? Am I doing something wrong with how I organised my templates for this to be not available?

**Edit** Okay, I came up with a workaround, in the for loop, before I include my template, I do

```
{% set post_index = loop.revindex %}
```

and use `post_index` inside the post template. Not ideal, but seems like the only way. I still want to know your solutions though.

**Edit 2** One other thing, I am able to access the `post` variable inside the `include`d template, but not the `loop` variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If might be possible with the [`{% with %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#with-statement) statement.

Try this:

```
{% with %}
    {% set loop_revindex = loop.revindex %}
    {% include ... %}
{% endwith %}
```

Instead of using `loop.revindex` in the included template, use `loop_revindex`.

Comment: Yep, setting it to another local variable is solution, I figured immediately after posting the question. See my edit to the question. Didn't require `with` though. Didn't know `with` too, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to pass the entire `loop` variable into the included template by setting a local variable to `loop`

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% set post_loop = loop %}
    {% include ["posts/" + post.type + ".html", "posts/default.html"] %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives you access to all of the `loop`s properties, and, to me, makes it more clear in the included template what the variable is.